# Two cars with different engines going at 100 miles an hour on the same route will be equal to each other on a no-traffic highway?

Tags: car

Consider a low end car with 660CC engine
and then consider a Mercedes with lets say 2000cc engine.

Both are going on same destination with 100MPH instantaneous speed currently on the same route with no other traffic.

Will they remain at the same level? I mean, considering the Speed = Distance/time formula, will they cover the same distance in the same amount of time and reach the destination at the same time i they maintain the 100 MPH at their odometer?

Assumption: Assuming there are no inconsistencies in the speedometer/odometer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about the repair and troubleshooting of motor vehicles.

Comment: Is a 2L engine considered "high end" now? I thought they still make +6L V8s, V10s, V12s... PS. the answer lies in the definition of *"same speed"*

Comment: Agree with @dlu ... this is off topic to the site. This is a math problem, not a maintenance problem.

Comment: Which is heavier, a ton of bricks or a ton of feathers....

Comment: @Moab a ton of feather, because you have to deal with the weight of killing all those poor birds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two cars are driving at 100 mph, yes, they both will be done 100 miles after 1 hour or 200 miles after 2 hours, exactly same distance, same destination. No matter what type or size car it is, unless one of the cars is Developed by Professor Doug DMC DeLorean :D
Only concern would be how long time 660cc car will need to reach (if it will reach) 100 MPH high speed :)
[image]

Comment: He states in the question, *instantaneous speed*. This means to me, they are both going the same speed at the start of this journey. Like I stated ... it's a math problem, not a maintenance problem. Great pic, btw. Everyone should have a flux capacitor in their car.